# Cannot stop 10 containers after Kubernetes minikube tutorial

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

[image: docker ps screenshot]

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7523fd2c20c7        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64         "/sidecar --v=2 --..."   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_sidecar_kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-qwc6z_kube-system_c1333ffc-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
9bd438011406        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64   "/dnsmasq-nanny -v..."   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-qwc6z_kube-system_c1333ffc-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
5c35e00a5a27        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64        "/kube-dns --domai..."   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_kubedns_kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-qwc6z_kube-system_c1333ffc-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
77ef463642b7        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0               "/pause"                 18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-qwc6z_kube-system_c1333ffc-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
39f618666205        gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64    "/dashboard --inse..."   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-vgpjl_kube-system_c1176a44-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
023b7b554a8c        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0               "/pause"                 18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_POD_kubernetes-dashboard-vgpjl_kube-system_c1176a44-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
1c3bdb7bdeb1        gcr.io/google-containers/kube-addon-manager            "/opt/kube-addons.sh"    18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_kube-addon-manager_kube-addon-manager-tpad_kube-system_7b19c3ba446df5355649563d32723e4f_0
8a00feefa754        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0               "/pause"                 18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-addon-manager-tpad_kube-system_7b19c3ba446df5355649563d32723e4f_0
b657eab5f6f5        gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner                "/storage-provisioner"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_storage-provisioner_storage-provisioner_kube-system_c0a8b187-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
67be5cc1dd0d        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0               "/pause"                 18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             k8s_POD_storage-provisioner_kube-system_c0a8b187-e4d6-11e7-bccf-0021ccbf0996_0
```

I just did the Kubernetes minikube tutorial at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube, and I cannot stop or remove these containers, they always get recreated.

```
$ kubectl get deployment
No resource found.

$ minikube status
minikube: Running  
cluster: Running  
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

Output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube   1/1       Running   5          19h
kube-system   kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-6kjsn     3/3       Running   15         19h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-68vph    1/1       Running   5          19h
kube-system   storage-provisioner           1/1       Running   5          19h
```

UPDATE:

I completely removed all packages called 'kube*', removed docker, remove virtualbox, removed /var/lib/docker, reinstalled docker.
And the containers are back! How on earth do you get rid of them?

Comment: You should paste the docker ps output instead of creating a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, Could you provide the `kubectl  get pods --all-namespaces`?

Comment: I added that output @SureshVishnoi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What containers do you want to delete and why? The containers printed in your `docker ps` output are Kubernetes containers. You basically would destroy minikube by deleting these containers.

In general Kubernetes manages these containers for you. Kubernetes interprets a deleted container as a failure and restarts it. To delete a container you have to delete the pod (or the ReplicaSet, ReplicationController or Deployment depending on your deployed applications).

---

If these containers actually appear on your host system, then you maybe installed Kubernetes accidentally on your host system (with another tutorial). In this case you have to look for a process called `kubelet` which creates these containers.

For example if you use systemd:

```
systemctl status kublet   # see if its actually running
systemctl stop kubelet    # stop it
systemctl disable kubelet # make sure it doesn't start after next reboot
```

Comment: I was only trying the tutorial and now I am done. Let's say I don't want to use kubernetes and just wan't to go back to working with docker-compose. How do I get rid of all of those services?

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of minikube. Minikube runs in a VM which is created for Kubernetes and has its own Docker daemon. It doesn't install Kubernetes components on your host system. Therefore the answer of @Andreas Wederbrand will fix your issue.

Comment: But I am on my host machine when I do the `docker ps`. I have now completely removed docker, and kubernetes packages, removed /var/lib/docker, reinstalled docker. But those service are back! Any ideas?

Comment: In this case you maybe also did another tutorial and accidentally installed Kubernetes on your host machine. I updated the answer for that case.

Comment: You are right, I was reading 2 different tutorials and I had also installed **localkube**, and after I deleted that service (and reinstalled docker), those containers were finally gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run kubernetes then minikube isn't needed and you can stop it and delete it.

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
```

Or, if you wan't it running, for some reason, just remove the environment variable DOCKER_HOST that `eval $(minikube docker-env)` set up for you. It points the docker client to the docker engine in minikube instead of your local machine.

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

Or, start a new terminal. It won't have the environment variable set.

Comment: But this does not stop and remove all my containers, which always get restarted? I am completely unable to get rid of them.

Comment: They run only in the Virtual Machine that minikube provisioned. Removing it also removes all of the containers.

Note that you still have to get a new terminal or unset DOCKER_HOST after you killed minikube, or you'll get an error saying the docker engine isn't responding. Or similar.