# How to find out the kubernetes master server corresponding to a worker node? How to kill residual k8s containers?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, minikube

1. I have no idea what is going on in my ubuntu VM. It was working as a 'worker k8s  node' once upon a time, but I have dismantled that k8s cluster TOTALLY. That said, there is no master now corresponding to this VM now.
2. But still, I see the below containers are running in my VM (Which I would still call as worker VM).

> 

```
 ~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2481e38e9a7a        k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      "/dashboard --inse..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-77d8b98585-c257p_kube-system_ecd335b0-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_1
8ca28af62b8f        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           "/sidecar --v=2 --..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_sidecar_kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-tj5rv_kube-system_edee9d35-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_0
9207d2eb56b2        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     "/dnsmasq-nanny -v..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-tj5rv_kube-system_edee9d35-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_0
031dab934bfa        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          "/kube-dns --domai..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_kubedns_kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-tj5rv_kube-system_edee9d35-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_1
13fe0b47078a        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kube-dns-54cccfbdf8-tj5rv_kube-system_edee9d35-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_0
b8560cb57ecb        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            k8s_POD_kubernetes-dashboard-77d8b98585-c257p_kube-system_ecd335b0-7469-11e8-b4d7-fa163e1912b6_0
```

3. I tried to kill the running container, stop them using kubeadm reset, I even tried removing all the k8s packages. The packages are all removed. kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet commands do not work, but as soon as I start docker service, above containers are created too.
4. I was also using minikube earlier, so I removed minikube packages.
5. On the previous master node, kubectl get nodes doesnt list this node.
6. How do I know which matser is tring to contact this?

Not sure how do I stop all those containers now. (Ultimately I want to make this VM part of anothe rk8s cluster)

Any help?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that neither minicube or kubelet service is running astray? Btw, what is `docker info` displaying? This is on your local setup, not on cloud/managed pool, right?

Comment: There is an instance of minikube running, even after deleting and stopping it. Whenever I delete minikube, localkube process is runnig again. The localkube is creating the noise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot stop 10 containers after Kubernetes minikube tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891870/cannot-stop-10-containers-after-kubernetes-minikube-tutorial)

Comment: Managed to get rid of it by renaming the localkube dirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf

This file has the IP to which it was communicating earlier.